# Get real exception type that is contained in AggregateException

Tags: c#, .net, exception

a database query is performed in a task which has a CancellationToken of 59sec. If the task is cancelled, a TaskCanceledException is thrown. But this exception is catched as part of a AggregateException.
I want to provide a specific error message. So is it possible to validate in the code if the real exception in the AggregateException is a TaskCancelationException?

Comment: `await` unwraps the AggregateException and throws the first of the `InnerExceptions`

Comment: Check the [documentation of the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception(v=vs.110).aspx). It shows how to access the inner exceptions, flatten multiple aggregate exceptions into one or use `Handle` to process all inner exceptions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `InnerException` or `InnerExceptions`, depending on your situation:

```
if (x.InnerException is TaskCanceledException)
{
    // ...
}
```

The above will work if you know you only have one exception; however, if you have *multiple*, then you want to do something with all of them:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (var inner in x.InnerExceptions)
{
    sb.AppendLine(inner.ToString());
}

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possible solution

```
try
{
    // the logic
}
catch (AggregateException e) when (e.InnerException is TaskCancelationException castedException)
{
    // here castedException is of type TaskCancelationException
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-catch-statement

Comment: Fantastic solution. This will eliminate hundreds of lines for complex exception handling that you see in this post and throughout code repositories.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the list of exceptions, or use the first one if there is just one:

```
var first = agg.InnerException; // just the first

foreach (Exception ex in agg.InnerExceptions) // iterate over all
{
    // do something with each and every one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the type of the InnerException worked:

```
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            if (ae.InnerException is TaskCanceledException)
            {
                LoggerService.Log(LogLevel.Error, "GetReport Request was cancelled");
                throw ae.InnerException;
            }

            LoggerService.Log(LogLevel.Error, string.Format("GetReport Request failed: {0}", ae.InnerException.Message));
            throw;
        }
```

BUT after the exception is thrown over the WCF Communication it is again encapsulated in an AggregateException.
And for some reason the mechanism to read out the second exception type is not that easy. But with the following it is working:

```
                catch (AggregateException ae)
                {
                    endMessage = string.Format("Defined Query failed. Error: {0}", ae.Message);

                    // Set specific error message when TaskCanceledException is contained in AggregateException
                    var fe = ae.InnerException as FaultException<ExceptionDetail>;
                    if (fe != null) if (Type.GetType(fe.Detail.Type) == typeof(TaskCanceledException)) endMessage = "Defined Query was cancelled";

                    logLevel = LogLevel.Error;
                    messageType = MessageType.Error;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Solution from [adriancho5692](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2684353/adriancho5692) is very good but only works if you only want to evaluate the first inner exception.

Here is one that search in all of the inner exceptions:

```
try
{
    // the logic
}
catch (AggregateException e) when (e.InnerExceptions.Any(x => x is TaskCanceledException))
{
    // here x is of type TaskCanceledException
}
```